# C++ Win32 changing default codepage

Tags: c++, winapi

I'd like to change the default codepage returned be *GetLocaleInfoA*. Right now it's 1250, but I'd like CP_UTF8 (65001). Do you have any idea how could I do that?

```
char szCodePage[8];
int iRc = GetLocaleInfoA( MAKELCID( GETLANG(), SORT_DEFAULT ), LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE, szCodePage, COUNTOF( szCodePage ) ); iRc;
ms_uInputCodePage = _strtoul( szCodePage, NULL, 0 );
```

Comment: [The `activeCodePage` manifest element can be used for more than just setting UTF-8 as the active code page](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220531-00/?p=106697). Requires Windows 10 Version 1903 (or later).

Comment: Doesn't really work.

Comment: @ErikSchvarcz in what way? Either [you are not using it correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page#set-a-process-code-page-to-utf-8), or you are trying to use it on an unsupported system. We can't see your setup.